# How much more likely is getting a prime number than a triangular number from a list of numbers from 1 to 100?

Tags: probability, percentages

> From a list of numbers from 1 to 100, how much more likely is it to get a prime number than a triangular number?

Solution:

There are $25$ prime numbers between $1 - 100$ so $25$%

There are $13$ triangular numbers between $1 - 100$ so $13$%

$\frac{(25 - 13)}{25}$

So it's $48$% more likely

Is this correct?

Comment: Try to explain to yourself where that number came from. Isn't it weird that there are almost double the number of prime numbers than triangular numbers but supposedly is only around 50% more likely?

Comment: Can you explain why you would perform division by $25$?

Comment: I don't really know how to do this. I just saw an explanation online but didn't quite understand it

Answer (score 1):

You know that the chance of picking a prime number is $25\%$. You know that the chance of picking a triangular number is $13\%$. You are looking for the *difference* in probabilities, therefore you should perform a subtraction.
$$25\%-13\%=\frac{25}{100}-\frac{13}{100}=\frac{25-13}{100}=\frac{12}{100}=12\%$$
Therefore it is $12\%$ more likely that you will pick a prime number than a triangular number. No need to divide by $25$. Hope this helps!